# Parse object of dynamic string with Moshi and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

I have a JSON like below.

```
{
    "code": "success",
    "response": {
        "data": {
            "xyz": "abc.pdf",
            "abc: "efgh.pdf"
        }
    },
    "message": "Files downloaded Successfully"
}
```

Inside data in the response object, the key is dynamic (xyz, abc etc). I am using Moshi in the retrofit converter. My data classes are as follows.

```
data class RestResponse<T> (
    val code: String,
    val message: String,
    val response: T
)

data class ProposalDownloadResponse(val data: DownloadData)

data class DownloadData(val list: Map<String, String>)
```

But I am getting **null** in the list after parsing. **Though I have data**.

Refrofit function is like below.

```
@POST
suspend fun downloadProposal(
    @Url url: String,
    @Header("accessToken") key: String,
    @Body flightDetails: FlightDetails,
): GenericResponse<RestResponse<ProposalDownloadResponse>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is You are nesting Object which is not needed . Your `data` itself is of Type `Map<String, String>` so `DownloadData` is not required.
Use it as Below.

```
data class ProposalDownloadResponse(val data: Map<String, String>)
```